# Perl eval block (nested eval ?)

Tags: perl, exception, nested, eval

I am executing some command within if elsif else based on some condition and store the return code
as $status.

```
eval {
    if ($condition1)
    {
      $status = system ...
    }
    elsif ($condition2)
    {
      foreach my $scenario (@setting) {
         next unless $scenario;
         $status = system <somecommand> 
         }
    }
    elsif ($condition3)
    {
      $status = system ...
    }
    else
    {
      $status = system ...
    }
};
die $@ if $@;
return ($status !=0);
```

I need to handle the below code , as this fails sometimes for some cases so 
I don't want program to abort completely in middle and keep on running. 
How I can handle this ?

```
elsif ($condition2)
{
  foreach my $scenario (@setting) {
     next unless $scenario;
     $status = system <somecommand> 
     }
}
```

Comment: Shirinsh, could you give us a runnable example that shows the problem? 
 As a reminder, don't forget the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52704375/edit) to include more information.

Comment: also you should be consistent in the way you write your blocks. I mean you can place the `{` on the same line as `for` `if` `else` `foreach` or on the next line, but please use always the same way to do so. it will make easier to read your code

Comment: Are you using autodie or IPC::System::Simple? [system](https://perldoc.pl/functions/system) does not die on error by default.

Comment: Yes, you can nicely nest BLOCK form `eval`s.  This is in general a way to control exceptions at cascading levels.  (How exactly to organize that is a bigger question of your overall design.)  But it'd be good to see what may happen in that `$condition2` and how it "_fails_."

Comment: Also note that testing `$@` is not a preferred way of checking for exceptions because there are several ways `$@` can become false before you check it, especially before Perl 5.14. See https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny#BACKGROUND for more details and http://mvp.kablamo.org/cpan/exceptions/ for a good writeup of the options.

Comment: @Grinnz I have to disagree with that. For one, it's been fixed (and 5.14 was a long time ago). Then, why not provide a link that talks about the problems that `Try::Tiny` has, as well? One reason would be a cleaner syntax, but then we do have that reverse sense there; most other modules have at least something to worry about. It's not such a clean cut. The link you provide is much more reserved and balanced about the choice, btw.

Comment: @zdim Some of it was fixed, but there are still two or three ways that `if ($@)` can fail to accurately detect that an exception was thrown, and the remaining cases aren't bugs. I linked Try::Tiny's docs only because they have a thorough explanation of the pitfalls of eval; I recommend Syntax::Keyword::Try now overall, for the reasons explained in that tutorial.

Comment: Using eval is still perfectly fine, but only if you understand why you need to use it like: `unless (eval { ... code ...; 1 }) { my $error = $@; ... handle exception ... }`, with an additional step of localizing `$@` in module code. This is a lot to explain to a beginner for them not to fall into that trap; Syntax::Keyword::Try is much simpler.

Comment: @Grinnz Well, sure that there may be issues with `$@` (only if you stray off of the reservation, btw) -- but so is the case with others (except that it's hidden in pretty syntax). I'd love to be able to simply recommend a module and for `$@` say "don't use that archaic stuff."  But I honestly can't.  And there is nothing terribly wrong with it: use it in _this way_ and you're fine.  Using exceptions correctly is far, far harder than following a particular prescription/syntax.  Note, if you know what you are doing then there are no problems.

Comment: @Grinnz I only disagreed with "_not preferred_." I think that there cannot be a consensus on that, given the state of the matter. We should also keep in mind that Perl's "exception" (one!) is, um, sketchy at best (is that a good way to call it?); perhaps basic and raw handling suits it just fine.

Comment: Please read https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Try#OTHER-MODULES ; you keep saying the others have issues, but the only issue I'm aware of with that module is that it requires a relatively recent perl and a compiler.

Comment: @Grinnz The `Syntax::Keyword::Try` adds keywords to the language. That's cool ... to the point of giving me a chill.  brrr.  Seriously, it's interesting and I liked it but it is a biggy step to take.  It's also at a ripe old age of 0.09.  Recall that there is _nothing_ about `$@` that we don't know.  Again, I like what I see about that module but I'd say that it's  too soon to throw all else in trash.

Comment: @zdim Keywords were pretty messy when they were using hacks like Devel::Declare but since 5.14-ish we have the keyword API which is supported by core and also used by popular extensions like Function::Parameters. Anyway I apologize for my wording, I am just trying to steer people away from footguns that have caused many problems over the years.

Comment: @Grinnz Well, that's fine but I disagree with "steering people away" so I offered my opinion.  I'm not up for "steering people away" from a fully understood and simple prescription to, at best, a new module that hasn't been tested (in the wild) well enough yet.

Answer (score 3):

The BLOCK form of [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) is the builtin mechanism for handling "exceptions" in Perl, which is [die](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html).

As such it is natural to "nest" it, in the sense that each level can have its own

```
eval { func(...) }; if ($@) { ... }

sub func {
    ...
    eval { func_lower(...) };
    if ($@) {
        # handle it: recover or re-throw for the higher-level handlers
    }
    ...
}

sub func_lower {
    ...
    eval { func_lower_yet(...) };
    if ($@) {
        # handle it: recover or re-throw for the higher-level handlers
    }
    ...
}
```

So at each level one can decide whether the exceptional behavior can be resolved, and if not then re-throw (issue a `die` again) as the higher level may be better informed to deal with it.

The exceptions in Perl also "bubble up," so if an exception is uncaught at one level  it is propagated up the call stack and the next level up can still deal with it (the program isn't terminated until the top level is hit with an exception that it doesn't handle).

Such a typical structure of nested calls is a little crammed in your if-elsif sequence but it still fits

```
eval {
    if    ($condition1) { ... }
    elsif ($condition2) { 
        eval {
            ...
        };
        if ($@) {
            # issue a warning, perhaps set some flag, and continue 
            # or throw a die for the higher-level eval 
        }
    }
    elsif ...
};
if ($@) {
    # interrogate details
}
```

This way you isolate (catch) exceptions from the code in the `$condition2` branch, and handle them in the `if ($@) { ... }` section, so they don't have to trigger the outer `eval` (unless that handler decides to re-throw).  Also see [$@ variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$@).

While I enveloped all code in the `elsif ($condition2)` branch in an `eval`, to blindly stop any exception raised in that whole code section and "protect" the higher scope from it, we can (and do) place those `eval`s more precisely around possibly offensive code

```
elsif ($condition2) { 
    foreach my $scenario (@setting) {
        ...
        eval {
            # code-that-may-die
        };
        if ($@) { 
            # handle error, or just report/print it and skip 
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Once there is an `eval` around a code section (or a statement) an exception from it is stopped and the code can continue (even with the loop in which that happens, for example).

Note that you can "throw" objects from `die`, for example of a simple class you write to pull together your needs, which allows for far more flexibility for the handlers.  Also note that there are modules on CPAN for all of this.

Comment: How can you "isolate errors from $condition2 so that they don't have to trigger the outer eval."? Thanks

Comment: How can you 'isolate errors from $condition2 so that they don't have to trigger the outer eval.'? Thanks

Comment: @user8657231  Any `die` that happens inside the `elsif ($conditon2)` branch (so inside the `eval`) is "caught" by that `eval`. This means that if code inside that `eval` throws/issues a `die` then `$@` variable gets set and the control goes to the `if ($@) { ... }` branch and one can do with that what one pleases; an exception that happens under `$condition2` is stopped from propagating further up and can be dealt with  in the branch `if ($@) { ... }`.

Comment: @user8657231   Note, the `eval` itself stops the exception from going anywhere. Even if you don't do anything at all in `if ($@) { ... }` (but say just report -- print -- that `$@`) the exception has been caught and is not going anywhere anymore.  Don't really need to have `if ($@) { ... }` at all for that --- by enveloping possibly offending code in `eval` the rest is protected from exceptions.

Comment: @user8657231  I edited and added to that part to try to make it clearer and more informative

Answer (score 0):

```
die $@ if $@;
```

tells your program to abort if something went wrong in the `eval` block.
if you remove this line, it should be fine.

after removing it you can replace your last line by something like:

```
return $@ ? 'something went wrong' : $status;
```

if you still want to detect if something went wrong without stopping everything, but this is not mandatory

Comment: I think we should wait for more information before suggesting to remove error checking.

Comment: @grinnz OP asks that the script does not stop when an error occurs. So yeah, that's not safe but I think this is the only way to fulfill the requirements